# How to not install GRUB when installing Elementary OS Luna?

Tags: system-installation, grub, boot-loader, elementary-os

I'd like to install eOS Luna, but I already have Debian 7.5 installed, so don't want to install GRUB again, as the last time I did this it broke the bootloader...
Is this possible?
I haven't seen any option in the Ubuntu installer, and as far as I know they are the same.